# Using ON UPDATE refference to non-primary key doesnt work?

Tags: android, sqlite

Two simple tables:

```
"CREATE TABLE categories(
_id integer primary key autoincrement, 
name text not null
);"

"CREATE TABLE expenses (" +
"_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
"category_name TEXT REFERENCES categories(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE , " +
"value FLOAT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, " +
"date DATE DEFAULT (DATETIME('NOW')) NOT NULL 
);"
```

I'm wondering why `"UPDATE categories SET name='new name' WHERE _id=1"` doesn't change category_name in all rows in the expenses table. Documentation says it should.

Maybe the field I'm refferencing must b a primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PK should be the "categories.**_id**" not the "categories.name", that's the problem.

Try this:

```
"CREATE TABLE expenses (" +
"_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
"category_id integer REFERENCES categories(_id) , " +
"value FLOAT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, " +
"date DATE DEFAULT (DATETIME('NOW')) NOT NULL 
);"
```

Comment: Damn, I was afraid of this. This is gonna  mess with my app a lot :/